# Ruby Object to JSON and back?

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to create a super simple database structure, but I do not want to use SQLite3 because I understand that my method is insecure. I want to be able to write my data object to a file, read my data object, and store it as a Ruby object to use.

```
irb(main):003:0> data['tom'] = Processing.new("Tom", "8347198738913", 1000) 
=> #<Processing:0x007fa75c841d30 @name="Tom", @limit=1000, @balance=0>
irb(main):012:0> data.to_json
=> "\"#<Processing:0x007fa75c0e9740>\""
```

Why am I not getting JSON? Where are all my vars?

Comment: You think your file will be "more secure" than sqlite3? What's "insecure" about sqlite3? In any case, `to_json` only makes sense if the object in question outputs something meaningful in its `to_json` call. `to_json` doesn't automatically know how to serialize arbitrary objects.

Comment: My method is insecure, not sqlite3. I just didnt want anyone to scrutinize my method. So, I would need to deserialize and reserialize between parsing?

Comment: If someone has access to your code, nothing you do is secure. If they don't have access to the code and the machine is properly secured then there is no need to jump through hoops, but instead just trust the security of the system to protect what you're doing.

Comment: is this in a rails app? Or just plain ruby outside of rails?

Comment: Maybe you should look into Ruby's [Marshall](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Marshal.html) class if you want to store Ruby objects on disk and reload them AND if you don't need cross-language support.

Comment: this is just plain ruby. FYI I ended up using YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Processing` class doesn't properly implement the serialization protocol of whatever JSON serialization library you are using and thus the library does the next best thing it can: use `to_s`.